# using an if to check a column in mysql_fetch_array while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a novice at PHP to do MySQL manipulations. When the problem is boiled down, the database has 2 columns - city, borough.  Some cities have a borough and the field is populated. Some cities do not, and the borough field is null. I only want to retrieve data into an array if the borough field is populated. My code looks like:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        if ( what_column_identifier_goes_here? != null ){
        /* For each row containing borough_data, put it in the return array */
        $row_array['city'] = $row['borough']; 
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
        }
    }
```

I tried searching for an answer, but I couldn't figure out good terms. From the search, I suspect this is deprecated. For the moment, I just want to get something working and then I'll learn PDO and make a whole bunch of changes in several scripts.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just use a better `SELECT` query.

Comment: I tried adding  AND borough != NULL to the working query. That doesn't work. What should I add to the WHERE clause?

Comment: Use `borough IS NOT NULL` or `borough <> NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, Back in a Flash. That works. If your solution was in an Answer, I would have checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($row['borough']) // do something
```

Or do it in the query:

```
SELECT city, borough FROM table WHERE borough IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming your query looks like

```
SELECT city, borough FROM ...
```

then you can use mysql_fetch_assoc(), which returns a simple associative array: fieldname -> value: (no need for the extra fetch parameter)

```
if (!empty($row['borough'])) {
    $city stuff....
}
```

with fetcharray, you have to count positions yourself:

```
SELECT field1,  field2,  field3, ...  <-- in SQL
       $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], ... <--- in PHP
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE borough<>''
```

perhaps this can help you quickly.
if you want more help then please visit at 
[http://www.w3made.com](http://www.w3made.com/)

Comment: I used your phrase to replace my if statement above. Don't know if that was your intent. Anyway the following does not work.   if ( SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE borough<>'' ){